# Is there any same method in swift to read InpuStream using post http request

Tags: ios, swift, http, input

Is there any same method present in swift to read the input stream from HTTP request

```
InputStream in = address.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

This is a local server is sending two response with 207:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express')();

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { 
  const x = "geeksforgeeks"; 
  const y = "geeksforgeeks"
  if(x === y) { 
    console.log('resolve');
    resolve(); 
  } else { 
    reject(); 
  } 
}); 

express.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log('send req1')
  // check if network exists and user requesting is owner of it
  return promise.then(() => {
    // add listener to receive response from gateway and forward it
    //_addGwEmitter.addGwEmitter.addEventListener(req, res, gatewayPsn);
    // send the gateway trigger instructions to coco user
    res.status(207).write(JSON.stringify({
      status: 200,
      msg: "Waiting for authorization\n",
      instructionText: "devProductInfo.instructionText",
      instructionImage: "devProductInfo.instructionImageURL"
    }) + "\n \r End" );
    // if no event is received from gateway trigger timeout after 60 seconds
                      res.setTimeout(6000,()=>{
    console.log('send req 2');
                                     res.status(207).write(JSON.stringify({
                                       status: 200,
                                       msg: "authorization done \n",
                                       instructionText: "devProductInfo.instructionText",
                                       instructionImage: "devProductInfo.instructionImageURL"
                                     }));
                                     res.end();
                                     });
  }).catch(error => {
    return res.status(400).send("error.getErrorInfo()");
  });


});

http.createServer(express).listen(port);
```

i want to read two response one by one 
i have tried 
uploadtask
downloadTask
dataTask

in HTTP URLSession.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer if you want to use 207 response in iOS devices then implement URL data Task with delegate and in data delegate, you will get the response data. make sure response content type is text/json